# BeanPropertyRowMapper does not understand joda time types anymore since upgrading to spring boot 1.4 / spring cloud camden

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-cloud

I have a Spring Batch Job that defines a `JdbcPagingItemReader` with a `BeanPropertyRowMapper` :

```
JdbcPagingItemReader<RawNotice> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select *");
sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause("from a_table");
sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause("state = :state");
sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey("id");

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("state", "interesting_state");

reader.setQueryProvider(sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject());
reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
reader.setPageSize(10);
// The line below is the interesting one
reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(MyEntity.class));
reader.setParameterValues(parameters);
return reader;
```

This used to work fine, but since we upgraded to spring boot 1.4 and spring cloud Camden, it throws an exception :

org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.sql.Timestamp] to required type [org.joda.time.LocalDateTime] for property 'ADateColumn'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.sql.Timestamp] to required type [org.joda.time.LocalDateTime] for property 'ADateColumn': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

The column ADateColumn is declared as a Joda LocalDateTime and stored as a java.sql.Timestamp in the database.

I'm quite aware I could add my own joda converters to the BeanPropertyRawMapper conversionService for example, or create a PropertyEditor that understands Java LocalDateTime, but that looks rather like a configuration problem, like something isn't being registered right.

Anybody with a solution/suggestion to fix this problem ?

Thanks !

---

This is the part of the entity that poses problem :

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "..." })
@ToString(of = { .... })
public class MyEntity {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Version
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int version;

    //<--- snip --->

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime aDateColumn;

}
```

Hibernate is version 4.3.11.Final

JPA is version 2.1 with Hibernate Entity Manager 4.3.11.Final

Comment: Please refer to https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SPR-13888/SPR-13888.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, but it refers to `java.time.LocalDateTime` not `org.joda.LocalDateTime` ...

Comment: Could you show us your definition of Entity? As well as Hibernate/JPA version.

Comment: @NghiaDo : here you go. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally ended up creating my own `BeanPropertyRowMapper` with custom Joda converters :/